# Excel Multiple Conditions Summing 

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, worksheet-function

I have Column A to A1600. In that column I have two project names "CP" and "GFI", in column B I have Project Phase 1-8, in column C I have the hours worked in each phase.  The projects intertwine so how do I Sum the hours for each phase?

I tried using Conditional sum buts its summing all 1600 rows that have the same phase for both projects?

Any answers?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot could better explain what you are talking about (post a link)

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2003 use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C:C*(A:A="CP")*(B:B=1))
```

SUMPRODUCT works like an array formula without being one, iterating through the columns one cell at a time.  If the conditionals are TRUE they are equivalent to 1, while if FALSE they are equivalent to 0, so it only ends up summing the values where both conditions are TRUE.

A simple way in Excel 2007 or newer:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, "CP", B:B, 1)
```

Just create 16 of these, one for each set of conditions.

Comment: I only have excel 2003

Comment: @RichardC, that takes a little more work, but can be done, I'll whip something up.

Comment: @RichardC, ok, edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Someone may post a better answer using array formulas, but I prefer sumproduct:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$1600="CP")*($B$1:$B$1600=1)*($C$1:$C$1600))
```

Comment: I think you might hit problems using sumproduct in excel 2003.

Comment: Yep, SUMPRODUCT is the way.

Comment: @Col - what sort of problems? I use sumproduct pretty often for this purpose.

Comment: @vairant I've only attempted it once so far and had to abandon it when a formula that worked perfectly in office 2010 generated #VALUE errors when opened in office 2003, maybe I was just unlucky or maybe it was a new feature that had been added in the later version.

Comment: It's a bit sensitive - you need to ensure that the arrays are equally sized. It also bugs out when you have a non-numeric value in an array you're trying to sum. I've never had problems beyond those two.